# I'm an amateur in mathematics and took up Fermat's last theorem as my project, and I have a question regarding that.

Tags: number-theory, computational-mathematics

Fermat has stated that there are no natural numbers $x$, $y$, and $z$ such that $x^n + y^n = z^n$, in which $n$ is a natural number greater than $2$.

but here is where I have my question.

For example let's take $n = 12$, and write

$x^{12} + y^{12} = z^{12}$, isn't this the same as writing,

$(x^6)^2 + (y^6)^2 = (z^6)^2$, now that we can convert even powers to powers of $2$, won't there be a solution?

Comment: $X^2+Y^2=Z^2$ has solutions, but none for which $X=x^6, Y=y^6,Z=z^6$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The existence of $x, y, z$ such that $x^2+y^2=z^2$ indeed implies that

$$\left(\sqrt[6]{x}^6\right)^2 + \left(\sqrt[6]{y}^6\right)^2 = \left(\sqrt[6]{z}^6\right)^2$$

and therefore

$$\left(\sqrt[6]{x}\right)^{12} + \left(\sqrt[6]{y}\right)^{12} = \left(\sqrt[6]{z}\right)^{12}.$$

However, to show that this means $\sqrt[6]{x},\sqrt[6]{y},\sqrt[6]{z}$ indeed represent a solution (and therefore, a counterexample to Fermat's theorem), you would also need to show that the three numbers are **integers**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Write it as
$$
(x^4)^3+(y^4)^3=(z^4)^3
$$
Indeed, the first reduction of FLT is to prove the statement for $n=4$ (which Fermat did) and for $n$ an odd prime.

Suppose $n>2$ and that $a^n+b^n=c^n$ for nonzero integers $a,b,c$. If $p$ is an odd prime such that $n=pm$, then we have
$$
A^p+B^p=C^p
$$
with $A=a^m,B=b^m,C=c^m$. If $n$ is not divisible by any odd prime, then it is a power of $2$ and, being $n>2$, we conclude $n=4k$, but then
$$
A^4+B^4=C^4
$$
with $A=a^k,B=b^k,C=c^k$.

Thus, if we exclude the cases $n=4$ and $n$ an odd prime, we're done. The case $n=3$ was done by Euler, so FLT was proved for any multiple of $3$, including $n=12$.

Comment: Euler also did n=5. In the 19th  century  FLT was shown to hold for an infinite set of prime n known as regular primes.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I don't think Euler did the $n=5$ case; it is attributed to several other people. Anyway, the case $n=3$ suffices for the purpose of the question.

Comment: I read that a 19th-century mathematician received so many amateur attempts at FLT that he made a form-letter: "Your proof of FLT has an error on page ..., line ..."